# Can I build .net core project for Mac on Windows?

Tags: .net, macos, asp.net-core

I know I can build .net core project to Linux application from Windows, but can I build .net core project to Mac application from Windows? Or do I have to install Visual Studio for Mac on a Mac virtual machine?

Comment: Have you tried? You don't need VS to build .NET Core app, SDK should be enough.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As far as I know, the asp.net core application is a cross-platform  developer platform, that means you could develop your application on any platform and running the application on any platform.

You could build the application on the windows platform and use publish to publish the application.

Then you could install the .NET Core MAC SDK and using `dotnet` to run the application.

More details, you could refer to this [article](https://www.michaelcrump.net/part3-aspnetcore/).